# Tidy does not quote ampersand

Tags: tidy

Trying to quote ampersand character:

```
echo 'a & b' | tidy -q --quote-ampersand yes --preserve-entities no --show-body-only yes
```

Result:

```
a & b
```

Expecting:

```
a &amp; b
```

Tidy version:

```
tidy -v
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.2.0
```

Comment: Same problem with HTML Tidy for Windows version 5.6.0. I'll come back if I find an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I moved some documents from XHTML to HTML5, HTML Tidy started changing all `&amp;` to bare `&`, and it ignored the `quote-ampersand` option.

As a workaround, forcing XML mode with the `input-xml` option works.

---

I'd still like a proper solution, myself. I dug into the code and found this possibly-relevant snippet ([from `pprint.c` on Github](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/blob/release/5.6/src/pprint.c#L818)):

```c
if ( c == '&' && cfgBool(doc, TidyQuoteAmpersand)
     && !cfgBool(doc, TidyPreserveEntities)
     && ( mode != OtherNamespace) ) /* #130 MathML attr and entity fix! */
{
    AddString( pprint, "&amp;" );
    return;
}
```

If `mode` is `OtherNamespace`, then the `&` character isn't changed. I don't know yet, but I'm guessing that maybe HTML5 mode changes the namespace handling so that it's always in `OtherNamespace` mode?